# Manipulating ArcMap Legend Graphics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, graphics

Is there a way to manipulate and edit ArcMap graphic legend items?

From what I found researching, one way is to convert the legend into graphics, ungrouping all the elements and editing each graphic element on it's own. But, by doing so, the legend seize to be linked to the table of content elements and any changes I make to the map are not reflected in the legend.

I would like to keep that relationship between the legend and the TOC while having control on the size, level of details and visibility in the legend.

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

See attached image as an example

[image: graphic]

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the settings on the Legend Properties - Layout tab?  Changing the Default patch height may allow more detail to show in your symbols.  You might also find that some symbols, especially those with a marker symbol fill, don't show the market as well as you like even after adjusting patch size.  One option is to create a copy of the symbolized layer and adjust the fill pattern of the markers and use that in your legend instead of the displayed layer.  You do have to change both every time you change your symbology so it's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: that's what I've done originally - make a copy of the legend, converted into graphics and manipulated the graphics. Unfortunately, playing the patch size did not work that well either. And you're right, this is a good solution for one or two maps, but in my case I produce maps on a daily basis.